# Setting = and @ properties in link function of angular directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

could somebody explain me or point to a document, which does explain the following question:
I am not able to set a '@' mapped property in the `link` function of a directive. However the '=' mapped properties can be set to a particular value in the directive's `link` function.
Working example can be found  [here in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jureh/1/watch?html,output)

I mean the following code:

```
directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      byValue: '@',
      byRef: '='},
    template: '<span>byValue: {{byValue}}<br>byRef: {{byRef}}</span>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.byValue = 'Custom Value set for byValue'; //this call is ignored!!!
      scope.byRef = 'Custom Value set for byRef';
    }
  };
```

The directive will render:

```
byValue: myProp
byRef: Custom Value set for byRef
```

Thanks and have a nice day!

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a object as scope property creates a isolated scope.

`@` binds a local/directive scope property to the evaluated value of the DOM attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are strings. This kind of one way binding with evaluated attribute value (not property).

`=` binds a local/directive scope property to a parent scope property. This like a two way binding.

For example suppose you write a html like this,

```
<tag test1="name"></tag>
```

And you have a scope value

```
$scope.name = "MyName"
```

In a directive you did

```
scope: {
  nameProp: '=test1',
  nameAttr: '@test1'
}
```

You will get

```
nameProp = "MyName"
nameAttr = "name"
```

When you do this

```
scope: 
{
    byValue: '@',
    byRef: '='
}
```

you can access parents scopes `byRef` property from within the directive and vise versa. That is why you are  getting

```
byRef: Custom Value set for byRef
```

In case of `byValue`, directives `$Scope.byValue` is populated with attribute value of parent Scopes `byValue` which in your case if probably `myProp`.

Comment: Thanks Muctadir for the answer. I can undrestand Your answer, but I still have a problem. In my example I am setting the `byValue` property of the scope in the `link` function. Therefore I would expect the have the value set in the `link` function in the rendered view. Unfortunately the rendered view shows the value which was mapped from the outside scope. It seems, that angular sets the value for a `@` mapped property after the `link` function call. Could You confirm that?